# How to get async/await function work with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have an async function called getUser() which is used to query the API, I also have a search field in the UI (component coming from Semantic UI React) and it will query the API based on the data.searchQuery value, please see the code below:

```
<>
  <Form.Dropdown
    search
    selection
    clearable
    fluid
    multiple
    width={width}
    name={name}
    placeholder="Start typing name to search"
    onSearchChange={
      async (event, data) => {
        const query = data.searchQuery;
        const response = await getUser(query);
        
       // other code
  />
</>
```

Currently, if I input 'test' in the search field, it will query the API four times (with 't', 'te', 'tes', 'test'), ***what I would like to achieve is only call getUser() function if the user finishes typing (for example, if the user doesn't type anything in 1 second then start query the API).*** I found some example in the [documentation][1] of Semantic UI React (Please refer to the complete code snippet in the doc):

```
 const timeoutRef = React.useRef()


const handleSearchChange = React.useCallback((e, data) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
    dispatch({ type: 'START_SEARCH', query: data.value })

    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
       if (data.value.length === 0) {
          dispatch({ type: 'CLEAN_QUERY' })
          return
    }

    const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(data.value), 'i')
    const isMatch = (result) => re.test(result.title)

    dispatch({
       type: 'FINISH_SEARCH',
       results: _.filter(source, isMatch),
      })
    }, 3000)

  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
    }
  }, [])
```

I tried to implement in the same way, but seems like I cannot do await inside setTimeout (await should only work with async function). How should I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: You should look into debouncing the event handler then... when the onChange event callback is not called for X duration, trigger logic.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` accepts async functions. You can pass an anonymous async function inline and it will respect `await`.

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(), ms));

const t0 = performance.now();

setTimeout(async () => {
  await delay(1000);
  const t1 = performance.now();
  console.log(`total wait: ${t1 - t0}`);
}, 1000);
```